# Excel Cost Tracking Equation

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to track the cost of individual items in Excel and the total of everything together.

As shown in the image, I need BL6 to equal `(AX6*$AX$39)` through `(BF6*$BF$39)`.

Is there an equation that doesn't make me type this out for each cell between AX & BF?

[image: excel snapshot]

Comment: How did you drag fill the formula? Down or right？

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly the problem is that you cannot copy the absolute references in the second part of the formula (eg $AX$39) across the columns.

You can do part absolute references, so if you change the formula to:

=(AX6*AX$39)

Then you should be able to copy that across the columns and the column reference will change but the row number (39) will remain absolute.

If you want a grand total in BL6 then SUMPRODUCT is the answer:

=SUMPRODUCT(AX6:BF6,AX39:BF39)